# Retrieving configured IMS role for D2L role

Tags: desire2learn

Is there any way to get the configured IMS role for a specific D2L role?

I am able to list all roles from this URL: `/d2l/api/lp/1.0/roles/`
which produces JSON such as:

```
[{
    "Identifier":"104",
    "DisplayName":"Administrator",
    "Code":""
},...]
```

but I don't see the configured IMS role for that role, also what does the `Code` attribute represent? On every role I've encountered, it's been empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the mapping between D2L *Roles* and *Org Unit Types* and the types supported by IMS is contained in the checkbox matrices in the **IMS Configuration** administration tool. These values are not currently exposed through the Valence Learning Framework API.

Also, the `Code` property on the D2L Role exists for integrations with a client SIS system, I believe; the SIS role code that maps to a D2L Role would then show up in this property -- if your back-end service doesn't have a D2L-provided integration with an SIS, then that explains why these properties aren't getting used.